# Сужение графика

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/c0ww4j12/1/

```js
 function otherRand(min, max){
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }

 function graphChangeMinMax(min, max) {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
 
  chart.yAxis[0].update({
   min: min,
   max: max
  });
 }

 $(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
     global: {
      useUTC: false
     }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
     title: {
      text: ''
     },
     tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      borderColor: '#000000',
      animation: true,
      shadow: false,
      style: {
       fontFamily: 'tahoma',
       fontSize: '11px',
       color: '#ffffff',
       lineHeight: '18px'
      },
      formatter: function() {
       return 'Время: '+Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x)+' <br /> Курс: '+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y)+'';
      }
     },
     chart: {
      type: 'area',
      marginTop: 0,
      backgroundColor: '#191919',
      plotBackgroundColor: '#242424',
      style: {
       fontFamily: 'tahoma',
       fontSize: '11px'
      },
      events: {
       load: function() {
        var series = this.series[0];

        setInterval(function() {
         var rnd = otherRand(51, 52);

         var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
             y = rnd;

          graphChangeMinMax(parseInt($('#graph_min_value').val()));

          series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 1000);
       }
      }
     },
     xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      lineColor: '#000000',
      tickInterval: 30000,
      tickWidth: 0,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      gridLineColor: '#414040',
      dashStyle: 'Dash',
      labels: {
       style: {
        color: '#f8f8f8',
       }
      },
      plotLines: [{
       label: {
        text: 'Время для покупки',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        x: 5,
        style: {
         color: '#ffffff',
         fontSize: 12
        }
       },
       color: '#ffffff',
       width: 1,
       dashStyle: 'Dash',
       value: (new Date()).getTime() + 15000
      }, {
       label: {
        text: 'Закрытие сделки',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        x: 5,
        style: {
         color: '#c43636',
         fontSize: 12
        }
       },
       color: '#b21717',
       width: 1,
       value: (new Date()).getTime() + 19000
      }]
     },
     yAxis: {
      gridLineColor: '#414040',
      title: {text: ''},
      labels: {enabled: false},
      opposite: true
     },
     plotOptions: {
      series: {
       color: '#d06807',
       fillOpacity: 0.6,
       lineWidth: 1.4,
       pointInterval: 30000
      }
     },
     legend: {
      enabled: false
     },
     series: [{
      name: '',
      data: (function() {
       var data = [],
           data_y = [],
           time = (new Date()).getTime(),
           i;

       for (i = -30; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        var rnd = otherRand(51.5, 51.6);

        data.push({
         x: time + i * 5000,
         y: rnd
        });

        data_y.push(rnd);
       }

       var min = Math.min.apply(null, data_y);
       var max = Math.max.apply(null, max);

       setTimeout(function() {
        graphChangeMinMax(min);

        $('#graph_min_value').val(min);
       }, 10);

       return data;
      }())
     }]
    });
   });
```

```css
#container {height: 400px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://isoption.com/js/chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<input id="graph_min_value">
```

Изначально график такой:

[image]

Но как только срабатывает setInterval, он начинает сужаться до уродского вида:

[image]

Что можно сделать, чтобы был изначальный вид и без всяких сужений он продолжал рисовать в таком же виде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин, чтож за каша-то это такая? Как вы в этом еще что-то понимаете?

Почему значение с плавающей точкой парсится как `parseInt`? И почему вы никогда не обновляете минимум?

Вот, держите: http://jsfiddle.net/c0ww4j12/3/